# Php Not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to programming but I'm sure there is a simple solution: 
When I try to use this code, I get no errors but the database is not updating.
I am having no trouble connecting to the DB. I have also tried variations of quotes. The update code works in phpmyadmin but not on the page. 
I am trying to update the information entered onto a form upon submission

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'dbuser';
    $dbpass = 'dbpass';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

      $mon_am = $_POST['mon_am'];
       $sql = "UPDATE `mydatabase` 
       SET `mon_am` = $mon_am
      WHERE `id` = 1";
           } 
    mysql_close($conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="mon_am.php">
            <input type="text" Name="mon_am">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is `mydatabase` a database or table ? because if it is a database, you cannot update a database directly. UPDATE statement is only for tables.

Comment: You don't execute your query (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  You should try and update to mysqli_ or PDO as mysql_ is not supported in newer versions of PHP.

Comment: `mysql_close()` is called outside your `if` and so may be called even if the connection isn't opened.

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: If `mon_am` is a string, you will need to have the content included in quotes ( `\`mon_am\` = '$mon_am'`), although as pointed out, look into prepared statements as this stops a lot of other potential problems.

Comment: ...and as @NigelRen pointed out, you're actually not executing your query. Just saving it in a variable doesn't do anything. I would suggest that you go through some of the thousands of tutorials/guides that's out there about PHP/MySQL

Comment: "my database is a table"

Comment: thank you ... I will try to use Mysqli and do some more reading....I thought this would be easy. just to clarify $mon_am is a variable in the form and there is also a 'mon_am' field

Comment: With the `mysql` extension, you need to execute [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-select-db.php) **before** you start executing any queries. But yeah, don't use it. PDO (easiest) or MySQLi (almost as easy) are the way to go

Comment: Personally, I would recommend PDO over MySQLi since that API is a bit easier. PDO is also an abstraction layer for the DB, which makes it easy to swap database (which is good for things like testing, when you want to use an in memory database instead) by simply updating the connection string.

Answer (score 3):

That should do the trick. Part of the credit goes to @Nigel Ren who pointed the fact that you forgot to execute the query AND that you should use mysqli or PDO.

Also note the use of prepared statement and parameters binding, which prevent the end user to post some nasty sql that will be injected in your query through the $mon_am variable.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'dbuser';
  $dbpass = 'dbpass';
  $dbname = 'YOURDBNAME'; //Change YOURDBNAME with the actual name of your database

  $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

  $sql = 'UPDATE mydatabase SET mon_am = ? WHERE id = 1;' //mydatabase must be a table, not the actual database name !!
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['mon_am']); //First parameter defines the data type
  $stmt->execute();

  echo $stmt->affected_rows; // This is only to show if the data was updated. You can delete it once your code is working

  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="mon_am.php">
        <input type="text" Name="mon_am">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

you must select your db after connect. 
Use mysql_query for executing your sql.

```
<?php
    ...
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $selectDb = mysql_select_db("yourDatabaseName");
    $mon_am = $_POST['mon_am'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `yourTableName` SET `mon_am` = $mon_am WHERE `id` = 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```